# Impersonation in web contact forms

Tags: email, security, spam, contact-page

Many websites have **contact us** form usually requiring sender's name and email address. Now assume someone uses the contact form but fills in an email address (a valid address) which does **not** belong to them.

What are the standard measures that the website's owner can undertake to prevent/mitigate such impersonation ?

Comment: There's a lot you can do with varying effectiveness and cost.

Comment: @JohnConde, any reference or keywords I can use to search for more information ?